# mock patch multiple user inputs in sequence

Tags: python, testing, mocking

similar questions have been asked many times, but I can't seem to figure out this simple test I am trying to build: I would like to first supply a "y", and then a "n" to a complex function requiring user input (i.e. it requires two inputs in sequence). This is my attempt - the with statement doesn't advance the iterator, but I don't know how I would implement patched input otherwise.

```
import mock

m = mock.Mock()
m.side_effect = ["y","n"]
    
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_my_complex_function():
    with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value=m()):
        out = my_complex_function(some_args)
    return out
```

Comment: This input/answers are sequentials?

Comment: strings - first "y" then "n"

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well the problem, you have a fucntion that have a similar behavior like this.

**module.py**

```py
def complex_function():
    first = input("First input")
    second = input("Second input")
    return first, second
```

And you would to like to mock the `input` builtin method. You were in the right way, the only point to fix is that you have to build 2 mocks. One for each `input` instance.

**test_module.py**

```py
import pytest

from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from module import complex_function

input_mock_y = Mock()  # First mock for first input call
input_mock_n = Mock()  # Second mock for second input call

input_mock = Mock()    # Combine the 2 mocks in another mock to patch the input call.
input_mock.side_effect = [input_mock_y.return_value, input_mock_n.return_value]

def test_my_complex_function():
    with patch('builtins.input', input_mock) as mock_input:
        result = complex_function()
    
    assert mock_method.call_count == 2
```

You may say: Ok, but how do I know that each input was patched correctly?
So, you can especify some return value to any input mock, so you can compare.

```py
input_mock_y = Mock()
input_mock_y.return_value = "Y"

input_mock_n = Mock()
input_mock_n.return_value = "N"

input_mock = Mock()
input_mock.side_effect = [input_mock_y.return_value, input_mock_n.return_value]

def test_my_complex_function():
    with patch('builtins.input', input_mock) as mock_method:
        result = function()
    
    assert mock_method.call_count == 2
    assert result == ('Y', 'N')
```